# How to update a C++ object from Lua

Tags: c++, lua

How can I define a function in Lua which will update an object passed to it from C++ (perhaps by a pointer or reference?). I am using sol2, and would like to update the `m_` data member of the `Foo` object `f` in the following C++ source code:

```
#define SOL_ALL_SAFETIES_ON 1
#include <sol/sol.hpp>
#include <iostream>
             
struct Foo              
{          
  int m_ = 0;
  void bar() { std::cout << "hello\n;"; }
};                   
         
int main(int, char*[])                                                          
{                                                                               
  sol::state lua;                                                               
  lua.open_libraries(sol::lib::base);                                           
                                                                                
  sol::load_result script1 = lua.load_file("test1.lua");     
  sol::function fx = lua["f"];
                                                                                
  Foo f;
  fx(f);                                                                                                                                                                              
  assert(4 == f.x);
                                                                              
  return 0;                                                                     
}
```

... my lua script currently looks like this:

```
function f(x)
  x:m_ = 4
end
```

Comment: Looks like metatable to handle attribute set, and write a function in C++ to handle that, then call that C++ function from lua.